# How to add two extra custom column in Sqoop Export

Tags: sqoop, hadoop2, sqoop2

I am exporting records from S3 to Aurora and while exporting i need to add custom value to the Aurora tables .

1. Current data time
2. Name of the file from which data is loaded in the table .

For example i have below record coming from File1.txt then the result in Table should be like

```
120280222|A||B|||SUNIL |C|D|371|124|9|CA
```

in the RDS output should be below

```
120280222|A||B|||SUNIL |C|D|371|124|9|CA|File1.txt|10-24-2018
```

Last two columns are extra .